# How to repeat for loop when the record count is one in ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ternary-operator

I have `ViewBag` which can have a count of one or two. If the count is one then I want some set of Html to repeat else if the count is two then I want the loop to execute normally.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Address; i++)
{
    if(i== 0) {
         <b>Current Address</b>
    }
    else{
         <b>Permanent Address</b>
    }

    <input type="text" value="@ViewBag.Address[i].Addreess1" />
    <input type="text" value="@ViewBag.Address[i].Addreess1" />

    //I tried doing something like
    i =  ViewBag.Address.Count == 1 ? 0: 1;     
}
```

But here the loop keeps on repeating is there anyway to check if the count is one then repeat the loop again else continue rendering as per the items within ViewBag.

Comment: Actually what you need to get done? is it to print something or else based on the count of the address? if so you just need a if statement, not a loop.

try this >>> for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Address.count; i++)

Comment: A down vote for what. If there was something unclear then would have commented like how @kumaDK has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't You just move this statement:

```
i =  ViewBag.Address.Count == 1 ? 0: 1;
```

inside for loop like this?

```
for(int i=1;i==1; i=ViewBag.Address.Count == 1 ? 0: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be is what you want:

```
@switch (ViewBag.address.Count)
{
    case 1:   // some set of Html to repeat
        @for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            <span> some Html item</span>
        }
        break;
    default:  // loop executes normally
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Address)
        {
            <b>@item.SomeProperty</b>
            <input type="text" value="@item.Addrees" />
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer here the thing is I have a long code of HTML If I do the above way then it will around 100 of lines I just want to check if the record is single then repeat the HTML content twice else if its count is two then the flow should be normal.

Comment: failing to ask a question properly will give wrong answers. down voting in a such situation is idiotic.

Comment: @kumaDK you're right, OK. but let to ask and clear it intead of down vote! :)

Comment: @User, ok, then replace the length (in line 4), 2. OR what is the problem with the above code exactly?

Comment: @kumaDK the above fits my requirement and I was aware of it but since the HTML will be more. I thought there might be something like as I described that  I tried doing something like i =  ViewBag.Address.Count == 1 ? 0: 1;

Comment: @AliAdl +1 for  your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are caring about the count-

```
var count = @Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.Address)
```

**Then-**

```
@if(count==2)

@if(count==1)
```

**Rectifying the code-**

```
   @{
     var count = Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.Address);
    }

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Address)
    {
       if (count == 2)
        {
          <b>Current Address</b>
        }
       else
        {
          <b>Permanent Address</b>
        }

       <input type="text" value="@item.Addreess1" />
       <input type="text" value="@item.Addreess1" />
     }
```